# multiprocessing.connection.Client connection retry time

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

in one of my programs I need to create a connection between two processes. I used the `multiprocessing.connection.Client` class in the following way:

```
address = ('192.168.1.128', 6502)
self.conn = multiprocessing.connection.Client(address)
```

My question is: how is the connection retry handled internally? In case the connection cannot be established do I need to take care of it or is the module handling it by itself? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit into the code I found that `multiprocessing.connection.Client` returns a `SocketClient` connection. In the `SocketClient` function a 20 seconds timeout is defined. If a connection is not established within this timeout after 10 ms another attempt is made. This will go on until infinity:

```
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20.    

def _init_timeout(timeout=CONNECTION_TIMEOUT):
    return time.time() + timeout

def _check_timeout(t):
    return time.time() > t


def SocketClient(address):
    '''
    Return a connection object connected to the socket given by `address`
    '''
    family = address_type(address)
    s = socket.socket( getattr(socket, family) )
    t = _init_timeout()

    while 1:
        try:
            s.connect(address)
        except socket.error, e:
            if e.args[0] != errno.ECONNREFUSED or _check_timeout(t):
                debug('failed to connect to address %s', address)
                raise
            time.sleep(0.01)
        else:
            break
    else:
        raise

    fd = duplicate(s.fileno())
    conn = _multiprocessing.Connection(fd)
    s.close()
    return conn
```

So I believe the answer to my question is that every time an attempt to connecting is made a 20 second timeout is started. If this timeout elapses after 10 ms another attempt is made.